# Determine which layer is on the front using JS

Tags: html, css, opera

I'm trying to change z-index of table cell using JS to bring it on top. Z-index only works when CSS 'position' is set to smth different than normal. The problem is that setting 'position: relative' and z-index for  does not work in opera.

So, i'm looking for a way to determine, whether  was brought to the front or not without using z-index. Maybe some DOM attribute?
Or maybe someone knows the way to determine position:relative browser capability or smth.

Thanks

Comment: Could you link to an example/test case? Are plugins/applets/iframes involved?

Comment: Thanks for help. I've found document.elementFromPoint function that helped me to write a workaround for Opera.
To see what I was talking about, please check out - 
http://sandbox.undsoft.com/opera/oh.html

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` other than `1` changes element's stacking context. `opacity:0.9999` might do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to help.